# Getting values from readonly columns when radgrid is in edit mode (inPlace)

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, radgrid

I have a problem with Telerik radgrid:

- i have a radgrid with 17 columns, only 6 are editables (others have ReadOnly="true")
- one button fires the method that tries to save changes into DB (not a radgrid event and     so i haven't grid arguments)
- i can get values from radgrid.edititems (6 columns) but I don't know where to find other 11 columns that are non editable...

here's my code

```
protected void HiddenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt = Oggetti.DT_RDO();

        foreach (GridEditableItem editedItem in dgRDO.EditItems)
        {
            Hashtable newValues = new Hashtable();
            //The GridTableView will fill the values from all editable columns in the hash
            editedItem.OwnerTableView.ExtractValuesFromItem(newValues, editedItem);
```

Into newValues i have edited values, where i can get other values???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

.ASPX

```
<Columns>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="ID">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Name" UniqueName="Name" HeaderText="Name">
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
    </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
</Columns>
```

.ASPX.CS

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditableItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        if (e.Item is GridEditFormInsertItem)
        {
            // insert
        }
        else
        {
            // Edit
            // Please add below code in your page
            GridEditableItem item = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
            item["Name"].Controls[0].Visible = false;
            Label l1 = new Label();
            l1.ID = "l1";
            l1.Text = (item["Name"].Controls[0] as TextBox).Text;
            item["Name"].Controls.Add(l1);
        }
    }
}
```

Note : We cannot get readonly column's value in ExtractValuesFromItem method. If we set any column as readonly then it will not rendered in editmode. That's why we are not able to access this columns.

After adding the above code you can able to see/get both column's value in ExtractValuesFromItem method.

Please check below link for more information.

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/reading-read-only-column-in-ragdrid-update.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by removing the ReadOnly attribute from the GridBoundColumn, and instead, disabling the editable textbox in the ItemDataBound event of the datagrid.

ASPX

```
<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="BillingRate" HeaderText="Rate" />
```

ASPX.VB

```
Protected Sub grdWorkServices_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs) Handles grdWorkServices.ItemDataBound
        If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem AndAlso e.Item.IsInEditMode Then
            Dim l_oGridDataItem As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)

            Dim l_oTextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(l_oGridDataItem("BillingRate").Controls(0), TextBox)
            l_oTextBox.Enabled = False
        End If
End Sub
```